# How install libevent extension in Apache2

Tags: php, apache, module, libevent, apache-modules

I try to install libevent in the php of my Apache2.4 in Ubuntu 16.04 but I can't do it.

I have this snippet of code for know if the library is detected in a test page on my apache server :

```
$test = event_base_new();
```

It says to me

> Call to undefined function event_base_new()

I miss some informations like I don't know if a library is considered a mod (I think no) but i found no documentation about libraries in the Apache2 doc.

I compiled the source libevent-2.1.8-stable from the official website and add the line in my php.ini (php/apache2) :

```
extension=/usr/local/libevent.so
```

I restarted my Apache2 but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `libevent` extension is not distributed with PHP. It is separate from the `event` extension, also separate from (but related to) the libevent C library, and it is entirely unrelated to [the Apache event MPM](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/event.html).

If you want to install the PHP `libevent` extension, you will need to install it from [PECL](http://pecl.php.net/package/libevent). However, that extension isn't compatible with PHP 7, and hasn't been updated since 2013, so you probably don't want it.

Comment: I installed event library with PECL.

But the event_base_new() function is a libevent function not a event function : http://php.net/manual/en/function.event-base-new.php. It is in the libevent section.

Now, the event function works, but not the libevent ones.

Also, the PECL from event and libevent have conflict : Failed to download pecl/libevent, version "0.0.1", latest release is version 0.1.0, stability "beta", use "channel://pecl.php.net/libevent-0.1.0" to install

Comment: Then you want the `libevent` extension, not `event`.

Comment: So, finally, the libevent one is outdated. I tried to installed it alone, and it requires an old version of PHP (<6).
Thank for the help.